# Hibernate one to many relationship: can't remove children once parent is removed

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a Course-Reviews one to many relationship. In Course table there are id and title columns. In Review table there are id, comment and course_id with "course_id" as the FK pointing to Course id. I wanna realize the scenario that once a course is deleted, the associated reviews should be automatically deleted. I have the following codes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Review> reviews;

    public void addReview(Review review){
        if(reviews==null) reviews = new ArrayList<>();
        reviews.add(review);
    }

    //other codes below omitted
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

//other codes omitted
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Client_OneToMany_bidirectional {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory sf = new Configuration()
                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                .addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Course.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Review.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();

        try{
            //add course and review
            Course course = new Course("How to learn Java");

            course.addReview(new Review("Good course!"));
            course.addReview(new Review("I love it!"));
            course.addReview(new Review("Need some more!"));

            session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println(course);
            System.out.println(course.getReviews());
            session.save(course);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            //start to delete the course
            session = sf.getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            Course crs = session.get(Course.class, 12);
            if(crs != null ){
                session.delete(crs);
            }
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
            sf.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I found that I could successfully remove the course but the three reviews were not deleted. I also tried to use orphanRemoval=true after searching stackoverflow related post but it still didn't work.

Comment: Show us the code of Course.addReview(). Also, why do you hard-code the id 12? How do you know it's the ID of the course you just saved?

Comment: I'm learning hibernate now so I hard-coded course ID to simplify my code. As I said, deletion of Course entry is not a problem. I have updated my code to include addReviews().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reviews never really belong to the couse, since you never initialize the owning part of the association: `Review.course`. Change your `addReview()` method to

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

public void addReview(Review review){
    review.setCourse(this);
    reviews.add(review);
}
```

Comment: But now if I removed a Review entry, the course got deleted too. How to avoid deleting parent while children is deleted?

Comment: Remove cascade = CascadeType.ALL on the ManyToOne association. it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Never mind. I adjusted CascadeType to not include REMOVE. Now I can remove reviews without removing courses